# Show that $C_{S_{n}}(\sigma) \subset A_n$ if and only if the descomposition in disjoint cycles of $\sigma$ contains all most $1$ cycles of odd length

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

> Let $\sigma \in A_n$ show that $C_{S_{n}}(\sigma) \subset A_n$ if and only if the descomposition in disjoint cycles of $\sigma$ contains all most $1$ cycles of length $1,3,5,7, \ldots$ and $0$ cycles of length $2,4,6,8, \ldots$.

I tried the following:

$\Rightarrow $) If $C_{S_{n}}(\sigma) \subset A_n$ then $\sigma$ commutes only with even permutations but $\sigma$ commutes with its cycles of descomposition, then these cycles are even and therefore our length are odd.

How can I conclude that at most there is one?

$\Leftarrow )$ Assume the cyclic decomposition of $\sigma$ as in the statement, and now let $\tau \in C_{S_{n}}(\sigma )$ then $\tau$ commutes with every  cycle $\alpha$ in the descomposition of $\sigma$

I tried to show that $\tau$ acts as a power of each $\alpha$ but I'm not sure about that.

Any hint or help, I will be very grateful for

Comment: Please remind us what $Z_{S_{n}}(\sigma)$ means.

Comment: @Shaun $Z_{S_{n}}(\sigma)=\{ \tau \in S_n : \tau \sigma = \sigma \tau \}$

Comment: Note: it's "commutes", not "conmutes".

Comment: From context, I think it means the centralizer of $\sigma$ in $S_n$.

Comment: I see. At least in English, we use $C$ instead of $Z$.

Comment: $\Rightarrow)$ If for example $\sigma=(123)(456)\ldots$, then $\tau=(14)(25)(36)$ commutes with $\sigma$